# How to Store Large Amounts of Real Time SNMP Data

Tags: python, django, database, scale, snmp

I am in the process of building my first SNMP application using Django, MySQL, Python, and Apache. It will monitor a few thousand devices that will have anyhere from 5-30 OIDS pulled from each device every 1-5 minutes.

I am wondering what is the best way to store data of this type?

- It would need to be something robost.
- Open to SQL or NoSQL
- No duplicate information (This could be easily accomplished by just storing the data every poll for every device but the constrains are it needs to be kept lean. So only storge of unique data)
- Schema of data should either be dynamic or somehow expandable.

I have truly run into the problem of scaling versus web development. Never thought this day would come!

Comment: What will be done with the data after collecting? I.e. will you aggregate the data somehow into hourly, daily etc? That could be a better way to save DB space than to try to invent some fancy "delta compression" algorithm. Then keep the raw data for a limited time and only keep the aggregated data for longer.

Comment: It will be called back to a user at will, the next step after this phase would be on how to visualize the data into graphs. It will have to collect the data at a constant rate. The only data that would have to actually be accrued overtime would be bandwidth, and latancy data. All other data should not even be entered into the database if there is no change.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option to store data like so is rrdtool http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/

You can create a separate rrd file for each OID per device.

Comment: I like this but it has some pretty high level documenation. I wish there were a big group of real world examples using this. I am finding some but I need to research further. I use python and I do see that there is a python module for it.

Comment: There few really good tutorials on the site with even samples how to store SNMP data http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/tut/index.en.html